# Canvas drawing limitation in java

Tags: java, android, canvas

i'm working on a navigation app in java that draws my steps on  a canvas. I want to lock the drawable area of that canvas so my app doesn't draw steps outside of the visible canvas area. Is there a way to lock my canvas?  Update : I have the canvas inside a framelayout.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="359dp"
        android:layout_height="379dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:background="#2D7DA3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerPP"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

        <com.example.uisimplu.Canvas
            android:id="@+id/step_surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".canvasdemo.PaintHomeActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/clear_draw"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/canvas_toolbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Paste this code in You**

```
    LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.lll);
    layout.addView(MyPaint);
```

**myPaint is object of Canvas class that's contains onDraw**